# Chain ContinueWith tasks

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, async-await, task

I have the following sample with two tasks. When the first is finished, the second should use the first's results. I am new in this field I I would appreciate if someone guide me how to chain it:

```
    public async Task<string> UploadFile(string containerName, IFormFile file)
    {
        //string blobPath = "";
        var container = GetContainer(containerName);
        var fileName = file.FileName;
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // await file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            // await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream);

            // upload only when the 'memoryStream' is ready 
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream))
                .ContinueWith(m => blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(m.Result)); // ??
        }
        return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
    }
```

If not the second variant:

```
public string UploadFile(string containerName, IFormFile file)
{
    var container = GetContainer(containerName);
    var fileName = file.FileName;
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream).Wait();
        blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(memoryStream).Wait();

        //Task.Factory.StartNew(() => file.CopyToAsync(memoryStream))
        //    .ContinueWith(m => blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(m.Result)); // ??
    }
    return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Comment: be careful your memoryStream life cycle, it will dispose before your first task finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the stream from the `IFormFile` and upload it directly

```
public async Task<string> UploadFile(string containerName, IFormFile file)
{
    //string blobPath = "";
    var container = GetContainer(containerName);
    var fileName = file.FileName;
    CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    await blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream())
    return blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

Comment: works well, in my variant was `blob.UploadFromStreamAsync(file.OpenReadStream()).Wait();` thanks a lot, however could you explain for the future how to use in that case ContinueWith?

Comment: @Serge do not mix async/await and blocking calls (`.Result` or `.Wait()`) you run the risk of getting deadlocks. Let the code flow async all the way through

Comment: @Serge For the most part, you shouldn't use ContinueWith.

Comment: so... I mean there is no way to do something like `await FirstTask().Then().SecondTask(firstTaskResult);`

Comment: @Serge you await them in turn `var firstTaskResult = await FirstTask(); await SecondTask(firstTaskResult);` provided the first task return a result ie `Task<T>`

Comment: @Serge Why do you use `.Wait()` over await?

Comment: I don't know... I am from synchronous world and is less verbose :) I will use await, you are right. I just wanted to know if there is something that links up multiple awaits..

Comment: You would have to do `await SecondTask(await FirstTask())` `await` gets the result from the task